# PowerShell in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2015

I am new to PowerShell and I am curious about its development in Visual Studio 2015.

In general, I was hoping that Visual Studio would show me available global functions defined in the project via autocomplete.

Is something like that even possible? It would be nice to have.

Comment: Install the PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio 2015 extension.

Comment: I already have that, however I am still not seeing our functions in the AutoComplete. I can only see native PS functions, but I'd like to see also global functions defined by me in project scope.